# How to display new android progress dialog in flutter plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, progressdialog

I am building flutter plugin and try to show native progress dialog with the code below.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog =new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading");
progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while downloading map");
progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
progressDialog.show();
```

And the dialog is displaying as below.

[image]

What I am expecting is default new android dialog when we create native android project like below.

[image]

What are the changes I need to do to make it work?

[Update]
This is the default AndroidManifest.xml code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.map_plugin">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

I have added application tag and added several style to this but none work

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"></application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your styles.xml file

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

And to use it:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading");
progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while downloading map");
progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
progressDialog.show();
```

Hope this will help you to achieve this

Comment: Ahh, I see. This worked finally

Answer (score 0):

Change theme in AndroidManifest.xml. See [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) for details.

```
<manifest ... />

    <application android:theme="<your theme>"
        ...>
...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Or try to pass the theme in `ProgressDialog(Context context, int theme)` constructor.

Comment: did't work, I have tried both plugin android AndroidManifest.xml as well as example application android AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Should be in the plugin as your dialog code is there. Please update your question and share code.

Comment: Could you check now, I have updated

Comment: I didn't notice second line, adding custom style for progress dialog worked.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this library:

https://pub.dev/packages/sn_progress_dialog

or

```
showLoaderDialog(BuildContext context){
    AlertDialog alert=AlertDialog(
      content: new Row(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:7),child:Text("Loading..." )),
        ],),
    );
    showDialog(barrierDismissible: false,
      context:context,
      builder:(BuildContext context){
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

don't forget to dismiss when your data is fetched.

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Comment: I am showing native dialog, not flutter dialog.